# C++ Multiple Inheritance (rhomboidal scheme) paradigm

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have 4 classes organized under Multiple inheritance rhomboidal scheme.

```
             BASE
             /  \
            /    \
        Deriv1  Deriv2
            \    /
             \  /
             Final
```

I have for each class "ShowXXXX()" methods (for example), where 'XXXX' is the name of the class.

When i call "`ob.ShowFinal()`" method it prints:

- Final's fields,
- Deriv1's fields,
- Base's fields,
- Deriv2's fields,
- Base's fields

**The problem** is that i want to escape printing Base's fields second time.
But, there is an paradigm: cause when i call "`ob.ShowDeriv2()`" it should be printed:

- Deriv2's fields,
- Base's fields

and when i call "`ob.ShowDeriv1()`" it should be printed:

- Deriv1's fields,
- Base's fields

**My code:**

```
// multipleInheritance.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//Summary:
//      
//      Mmb - member
//      Prm - parameter
//      b - Base
//      i1, i2 - Intermediate1, Intermediate2
//      f - final

class Base
{
    int bMmb;

public:
    Base(int);
    void ShowBase();
};

Base::Base (int bPrm)
{
    bMmb = bPrm;
}

void Base::ShowBase()
{
    cout << "Showing Base fields" << endl;
    cout << "bMmb = " << bMmb << endl; 
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl << endl;
}

class Intermediate1 : public Base
{
    int i1Mmb;

public:
    Intermediate1(int, int);
    void ShowIntermediate1();
};

Intermediate1::Intermediate1(int bPrm, int i1Prm):Base(bPrm)
{
    i1Mmb = i1Prm;
}

void Intermediate1::ShowIntermediate1()
{
    cout << "Showing Intermediate1 fields" << endl;
    cout << "i1Mmb = " << i1Mmb << endl;
    ShowBase();
}

class Intermediate2 : public Base
{
    int i2Mmb;

public:
    Intermediate2(int, int);
    void ShowIntermediate2();
};

Intermediate2::Intermediate2(int bPrm, int i2Prm):Base(bPrm)
{
    i2Mmb = i2Prm;
}

void Intermediate2::ShowIntermediate2()
{
    cout << "Showing Intermediate2 fields" << endl;
    cout << "i2Mmb = " << i2Mmb << endl;
    ShowBase();
}

class Final : public Intermediate1, public Intermediate2
{
    int fMmb;

public:
    Final(int, int, int, int);
    void ShowFinal();
};

Final::Final(int bPrm, int i1Prm, int i2Prm, int fPrm): Intermediate1(bPrm, i1Prm), Intermediate2(bPrm, i2Prm)
{
    fMmb = fPrm;
}

void Final::ShowFinal()
{
    cout << "Showing Final fields" << endl;
    cout << "fMmb = " << fMmb << endl;
    ShowIntermediate1();
    ShowIntermediate2();
}

void main()
{
    Base t(1);
    t.ShowBase();

    Intermediate1 u1(2, 31);
    u1.ShowIntermediate1();

    Intermediate2 u2(4, 51);
    u2.ShowIntermediate2();

    Final v(6, 71, 72, 8);
    v.ShowFinal();
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: You would use virtual inheritance to ensure that `Final` gets only one `BASE` subobject as opposed to two in the non-virtual inheritance case. But virtual inheritance does have a cost - it increases the size of the `Deriv1` and the `Deriv2` subobjects and it's somewhat more complicated to use. And I can't help to think but there's a more fundamental problem with your design. What is it you're actually trying to do? Are all the `Show*()` methods just there for debugging or what?

Comment: It smells a bit like you are using inheritance when you should be using composition. Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve with that code?

Comment: I should do a work proposed by my professor at the laboratory training courses. It is a simple example where he said "Try to make a multiple inheritance under rhomboidal form"

Comment: @Insilico "_and it's somewhat more complicated to use._" what kind of complications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very little constraints in your question, so this should work.

Change the declaration in Intermediate1 (and 2) to

```
public:
    void ShowIntermediate1(bool printBase = true);
```

And in the implementation:

```
...
if (printBase)
 ShowBase();
```

Then in `ShowFinal()`:

```
ShowIntermediate1(true);
ShowIntermediate2(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer you are looking for is [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance). Which is designed to solve [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem). But you should change your code to use virtual methods then.